# uWSGI: Python's concurrent.futures hang on all but one uWSGI process

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

I'm using Python's concurrent.futures module (module version 2.1.3, Python version 2.7.3). I have nginx running with 4 worker processes, and 4 uWSGI running (on Ubuntu precise) as an upstart daemon, with the following uwsgi config (note enable-threads is true, so the GIL is accessible, and lazy is true):

```
virtualenv=[ path to venv ]
chdir=[ path to python project ]
enable-threads=true
lazy=true
buffer-size=32768
post-buffering=true
processes=4
master=true
module=[ my app ].wsgi
callable=wsgi_app
logto=/var/log/uwsgi.log
pidfile=[ replaced ]
plugins=python27
socket=[ replaced, but works fine ]
```

The entire app works fine, but it seems that some missing context is not available to the futures pool: When I call somefunc() without future(), all is well, but when I call somefunc() with future, the HTTP request (I'm using Flask) hangs for quite some time before failing.

The only entries to the log file are related to HTTP requests, and general wsgi startup stuff like:

```
WSGI application 0 (mountpoint='') ready on interpreter 0x11820a0 pid: 26980 (default app)
```

How can I get some visibility into the futures execution, or figure out what context might not be available to the futures pool?

Does that make sense?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using  ProcessPoolExecutor instead of threads, be sure to add close-on-exec to your uWSGI options, otherwise the connection socket with the client/webserver will be inherited after fork()

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion, but I'm not having any luck. I added:

    close-on-exec=true

... to my uWSGI config and restarted nginx and uWSGI. I can see why that might solve the problem, but I'm still getting timeouts.

Comment: Actually, maybe I don't understand. To clarify.. basically the process spawning the future will, by default, inherit the file descriptors of that the spawner has open. Why would this cause a timeout, though?

Comment: because when you inherit a file descriptor you have two reference to it and when the worker close the connection the socket remains open

Comment: Gotcha. Enabled close-on-exec and restarted, but to no effect.

It turns out that the timeouts were due to the futures pools not being spun up for some uWSGI child processes. So now the problem is not hanging, but a lack of visibility into why the futures calls are failing.

Comment: well you should post some code, maybe something interfere with multiple workers (even if nothing popup in my mind)